# @ManyToMany using 4 tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

[image: schema]

How to join `users` and `service` through this two tables?

`@JoinTable` works perfect when you have relation through 1 table. But what to do in this case?

This is possible without creating separate entities for `admins` and `admin_to_service`?

Comment: since User and Service dont have any way of providing "admin_id" (to use admin_to_service table) and dont have a way of providing "role_id" (to use admins table) then you can conclude that you CANNOT model that with straight JPA without introducing intermediate entities. Any JPA docs show how to do O-O relations

Comment: though not direct mapping, you could use JPA queries

Comment: Does the relationship need to be updateable?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a view to function as the Join table. I don't know what your FK references are but something like:

```
create or replace view user_services_vw as
select 
    a.user_id,
    ats.service_id
from 
    admins a
inner join 
    admin_to_services ats on ats.some_col. = a.some_col
```

You can then model as a simple `@ManyToMany`. This should work fine if the relationship is read only but you may have issues if the data needs to be updateable.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_services_vw")
    private Set<Service> services;

}
```